# Why doesn't mydict.items().sort() work?

Tags: python, dictionary

When I try and sort my dictionary, I get an error: ''nonetype' object is not iterable.

I am doing:

```
for k,v in mydict.items().sort():
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `sort` method returns `None` (it has sorted the temporary list given by `items()`, but that's gone now).  Use:

```
for k, v in sorted(mydict.iteritems()):
```

Using `.items()` in lieu of `.iteritems()` is also OK (and needed if you're in Python 3) but, in Python 2 (where `.items()` makes and returns a list while `.iteritems()` doesn't, just returns an iterator), avoiding the making of an extra list is advantageous -- `sorted` will make its own list to return, anyway, without altering the argument passed to it.